# Event receiver not populating list as expected

Tags: event-receivers

I have created an event receiver that does two things: 
1) Pulls information from a selected user's profile and populates a column with that information (BC Champion ID).  <-- This part works 
2) Extracts the first Cost Center from a list of Cost Centers (Column is named 'Cost Center(s)') and populates a column, (CC)  <-- This part does not work. 
 Stepping through the code, I can see that properties.ListItem["CC"] is populated like I would expect before ListItem.Update() but afterward, the column is slightly changed, such that preceeding 0s are truncated and ;# is added to the end of the string.  Although properties.ListItem["CC"] seems to be populated via the event receiver, it is indeed blank when I check the list item.  Any ideas?

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       EventFiringEnabled = false;
       string userID = properties.ListItem["BC Champion"] as string;
       //string userID = properties.AfterProperties["BC_x0020_Champion"] as string;
       SPFieldUserValue userName = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, userID);
       string selectedUser;
       if (userName.User != null)
       {
           selectedUser = userName.User.LoginName;
       }
       else
       {
           selectedUser = userName.LookupValue;
       }

       var user = GetUserInfo(selectedUser);
       properties.ListItem["BC Champion ID"] = user["corpID"].Value;
       //properties.AfterProperties["LookupBU"] = getLookUpValue(user["BU"].Value.ToString(), properties.List, "LookupBU");

       string CCs = properties.ListItem["Cost Center(s)"].ToString();
       string[] parts = CCs.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
       string primaryCC = parts[1];
       properties.ListItem["CC"] = primaryCC as string;
       properties.ListItem.Update();
       EventFiringEnabled = true;
   }

   private UserProfile GetUserInfo(string accountName)
   {
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2010/sites/MyBCP2"))
       {
           SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
           UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

           UserProfile testUser = profileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
           return testUser;
       }
   }
```

Watch before ListItem.Update()

```
CCs                       "1304;#02163;#107;#01006"
primaryCC                 "02163"
properties.ListItem["CC"] "02163"
```

Watch after ListItem.Update()

```
CCs                       "1304;#02163;#107;#01006"
primaryCC                 "02163"
properties.ListItem["CC"] "2163;#"
```

Comment: not sure why you are first calling base.ItemAdding(prop) in your ItemUpdated event handler or would it matter?

Comment: Thanks!  I took it out but I see the same behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just deleting and recreating the column with another name and changing my code to reference the new column.  It works fine.  I never found out what the issue was with the original column.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the Column "CC" is defined ad a lookup column and when you give that just a string with a number instead of a SPFieldLookupValue rightly constructed it assumes that the number is just the ListId of the row in the lookup table.

The right value to assing "CC" is probably "1304;#02163"

But you should populate it using code like this:

```
var CCs = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection((string)properties.ListItem["Cost Center(s)"]);
properties.ListItem["CC"] = CCs[0];
```

Comment: Good Guess but CC is just a single line of text column.  The 'Cost Center(s)' column is a lookup column though.

Comment: If it really is a Single line of text then you should report the bug to MS, but I don't believe you

Comment: I checked again.  I promise it is a single line of text field...  =(